# Typescript type pattern is not working on return from array

Tags: typescript

I want to have a list of array whose string pattern are /key-/, I am using typescript, but getting type error for keysArray. I Need help in fixing the type error for keysArray.
Thank you

```js
const temp: any = {a:1, b:2, "key-1":3, c:4, "key-2":5}


type IKey = `key-${number}`

const keysArray: IKey[] = Object.keys(temp).filter((eachKey: any) => /key-/.test(eachKey));


interface ISome {
    [key: IKey]: string
}

const obj: ISome = {
    "key-1": "hello"
}
```

[Link to the demo here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCmBbADgLhgQzATxgXhgG8NUBGAGhgCNUAmSgIgGt5sBaUh1AZkuFQAsjFu1pcArAF8AULKjZk8GAEkA0q3wwABiLYASQmACuiKvABOkrbNCRYIiAEFz5jNnRrWAbQC6mgPJUAFbwwFAAdA4AFAgoAJThAGYAlgA2COZRUfAYwAAW6u6YOHH4AHwwAPS6leEI0Nm5BaxxcQDcstLJYBmJuUrKAMogiEqE0jCTMF4iHoU+6NDm3QDm0jLSttAwIMEew6Oa41MwzKwcXKd58KmpIAzrQA)

I tried adding `as unknown as IKey` to the filter function, that didn't resolve the type error

Answer (score 1):

If you want `.filter` to product an array with narrowed types, you need to make your function into a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). Ie, it needs the special return type "eachKey is IKey":

```
const keysArray: IKey[] = Object.keys(arr).filter(
  (eachKey: string): eachKey is IKey => /key-/.test(eachKey)
);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQLhtBBLMBzA2gXRgF4ZcAiOMgGhjICNraBrAUwE8BaARkbOF9acATGXwAoCVDYAHFjACSAaXbEYAA0EcAJAG8wAVwC2dFggC+aiaEixBEAIJI4bVEvYFVAeToArFsCgAOjsACkQEAEpAgDMMABsoUxCxGBgQljhgAAtlFzQoTBwI1Azs3JgMCAVyogA+GAB6TQbAxOh0zJz2CLEIgG4JLESEaMy5eQBlEEM5HRTU0kFXXPxUdCxsMTMrcGgYEF9XKZnVOYXmdm4yVDIslji4kDItoA)

P.S, i think it's a mistake that you used `Object.keys(arr).filter` here. `Object.keys(arr)` is going to give you an array of `["0", "1", "2", 3", /*etc*/]`. Ie, the indexes of the array. Instead you probably meant to do `arr.filter`

Comment: I'm sorry, It was an object. I added as Array by mistake while posting